# Blender 2.8 Beta Vincent Eye movement problem

Tags: animation

I'm testing the [Vincent](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5718a967c379cf04929a4247) character in version 2.80-4ef09cf937f2.
It seems that the eye texture does not rotate correctly along with the eye object.
Even though it looks correct in the viewport. This does not happen in v2.79. How do I fix this?
[image]
[image: Rendered]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a feature that hasn't been implemented in eevee.
[Eevee - Generated coordinates don't follow mesh deformation](https://developer.blender.org/T59275)

Comment: it looks like it's fixed: https://developer.blender.org/rB0b40af97f41137b083dedbf64b0685f9f0fb1987